# mongodb empty is the wildcard but only on top level?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

sorry to those who do not like Python my samples use pymongo.

In mongodb empty is used as "wildcard" like the here (using the "wildcard" I get same or more results):

```
>>> projects.find_one({'name': 'boodo3', '_id': ObjectId('4efa14c6b0ab584326000000')})
{u'_id': ObjectId('4efa14c6b0ab584326000000'), u'name': u'boodo3', u'updated_at': u'2011-12-28 13:47:09'}
>>> projects.find_one({'name': 'boodo3'})
{u'_id': ObjectId('4efa14c6b0ab584326000000'), u'name': u'boodo3', u'updated_at': u'2011-12-28 13:47:09'}
```

but if I am querying "inside" of the document the wildcards do not work any more like in the following sample:

```
>>> testruns.find_one({'_parent': {'_coll': u'projects', '_id': '4efa14c6b0ab584326000000'}})
{u'_parent': {u'_coll': u'projects', u'_id': u'4efa14c6b0ab584326000000'}, u'_id': ObjectId('4efa167eb0ab584351000002'), u'name': u'11121617', u'updated_at': u'2011-12-27 19:03:26'}
>>> testruns.find_one({'_parent': {'_coll': u'projects'}})
>>> <no results here>
```

I tried variations using '$in' and '$nin' but so far without luck. I hope there is some structured way of querying documents (I mean something besides regex). I would restructure my collections if necessary but I believe that flat documents are not the solution here.

Does that mean I have to translate all the queries into dot-notation?
Or are regex the way to query documents in mongodb?

disclaimer: I do not intent to criticize mongodb or anything. This is my first app which uses mongodb and I want to learn how to query documents in mongodb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query:
`testruns.find_one({'_parent': {'_coll': u'projects'}})`
Is looking for documents where the _parent is equal to `{'_coll': u'projects'}` which does not have any matches because the document has other keys in it as well, so equality is not satisfied - there is no notion of "wildcard" here. Try your query like this:

`testruns.find_one({'_parent._coll': u'projects'})`

Comment: I am currently transforming the queries into dot-notation like in your sample and it looks very promising so far. I hope the performance of queries using dot-notation is good, too.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the title as the question itself is incorrect.

**"How to search nested document criteria in mongodb"** which is a duplicate:

[How to correctly query a MongoDB nested document with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295266/how-to-correctly-query-a-mongodb-nested-document-with-python)

This is also answered in the mongodb docs here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/

Under "Specify Equality Match on a Nested Field"